# Yii2: Handle dropdown data to widget

Tags: yii2

I'm building a widget on Yii2 that displays charts.

I have the defining ChartsWidget class file.

```
class ChartsWidget extends Widget
{
    public $limit;

    public $topten;

    public $type;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if ($this->limit === null) {
            $this->limit = 10;
        }
        $this->topten = $this->GetTopTen();
        if ($this->type === null) {
            $this->type = "column";
        }else{
            $this->type=
        }
    }

    private function GetTopTen()
    {
        $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

        $command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT colonias.nomasen AS name, count(rv.geom) AS conteo FROM colonias LEFT JOIN rv ON ST_Contains(colonias.geom, rv.geom) WHERE colonias.nomasen!='NINGUNO'  GROUP BY  colonias.nomasen ORDER BY conteo DESC LIMIT :limit")->bindValue(':limit', $this->limit);

        $tops = $command->queryAll();

        foreach ($tops as $top) {
            $topten['names'][]=$top['name'];
            $topten['conteos'][]= $this->ToInt($top['conteo']);
        }

        return $topten;
    }

    
    private function ToInt($valor)
    {
        return (int)$valor;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->render('charts', ['topten' => $this->topten, 'limit' => $this->limit, 'type' => $this->type]);
    }
}
```

I have two views "type" that is an ActiveForm. I want it to be a type selector.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;

?>

<div class="type-search" style="float: left; width: 48%;">

    <?php    
    
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['type'],
        'method' => 'get',
    ]); 

    $data = ["column", "bar", "pie"];

    echo '<label class="control-label">Tipo</label>';
    echo Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'state_10',
        'data' => $data,
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Selecciona un tipo'
        ],
    ]);

    ?>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

How do I pass the selected item in the dropdown list to ChartsWidget???

I tried `$query = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;` it doesn't work.

Obviously, ChartsWidget has no actions like any controller has.

**EDIT**

I am using dropdown because I want the user to select the type of chart like bars, columns, pie, etc.

I'm calling the widget in Maps view like this

```
<?= ChartsWidget::widget(['limit' => 12, 'type' => 'bar']) ?>
```

This is the view Maps[image: view]

I can access type using `'type' => 'value'` like above. But I want user to select type.

By the way, I am using `Kartik/select2` widget for dropdown lists. And `2amigos` chart plugin which I use to make my own widget.

**DONT GET CONFUSED**

This might be a little confusing. What I am looking for is. How do I pass selected drop-down data in the active form to `ChartsWidget` class. And how to get that data in `ChartsWidget` class.

I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: you might need to add a little bit more info that what are you changing on the dropdown selection i cant see your widget called anywhere in your code ?

Comment: I have added what you asked for.

Comment: ok but you didnt added the widget code in the exact place/view you are using it what i m trying to understand is that why are you creating a select dropdown outside the widget as a part of the form rather than keeping it inside the widget? as you need to change the chart on the change of the dropdown why dont you keep the search form as part of the widget

Comment: well actually it is part of the widget. ChartsWidget has two views, type->displays the dropdown and charts->that displays the charts. My views are in app\componets\charts\views and my ChartsWidget class is in app\components\charts\ChartsWidget.php

Comment: hmm ok, i added an answer below with javascript usage if that works out for you, otherwise you should submit the page or reload the page and send the selected type via query string in the url and use `Yii::$app->request->queryParams['type']` to ge the type inside the view file of your widget where you are passing the `type` option to your widget.

Comment: i updated my answer see if that helps you out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the javascript at this part to change the chart you should use the `options` and `methods` for the `chart.js` to change it on runtime you can use `.update()` to re-draw the chart along with the data if it needs to be different too.

[**`Here`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) is the link to the section.

A simple example to draw a chart is like below

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

now if I want to change the chart type to `bar` from `line` i can update the option with

```
myLineChart.config.type='bar';
myLineChart.update();
```

The above 2 lines need to be bound to the button or in your case the `select2`

A simple example to change the chart with a button click in native `HTML` and `javascript` is below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  $("#change-bar").on('click', function() {
    myChart.config.type = 'line';
    myChart.update();
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<button id="change-bar">change graph</button>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

As you want to change the chart by using `kartik/select2` you can use the event under the `pluginEvents`

```
"select2:select" => "function() {  }",
```

Your select2 should look like below

```
echo Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'state_10',
        'data' => $data,
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Selecciona un tipo'
        ],
        'pluginEvents'=>[
            "select2:select" => "function(e) { 
              myLineChart.config.type=$(this).val();
              myLineChart.update(); }",
         ]
    ]);
```

The above requires that the variable `myLineChart` to be available where you are trying to populate the select dropdown.

Ideally, you should initialize the code related to the select2 inside the widget as a part of it or pass the id of the select element to your widget and bind the change event inside your widget where you register your scripts.

---

### EDIT

Another solution could be appending the selected value from the drop-down to the `URL` as query string parameter and reload the page with the new URL, and then assigning it to the class option `$type` inside the `init()` using `Yii::$app->request->queryParams`, and pass it to your view file where you are calling the chart widget like below

```
<?= ChartsWidget::widget(['limit' => 12, 'type' => $type]) ?>
```

your view where you are populating the  code will look like below in that case

```
$data = ["column", "bar", "pie"];    
$baseUrl=\yii\helpers\Url::current(['type'=>null]);

echo \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'state_10',
        'data' => $data,
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Selecciona un tipo'
        ],
        'pluginEvents'=>[
            "select2:select" => "function(e) { location='$baseUrl?type='+$(this).select2(\"data\")[0].text}",
         ]
    ]);
```

In your `ChartWidget` class inside the `init()` function add the following

```
if(isset(Yii::$app->request->queryParams['type'])){
      $this->type=Yii::$app->request->queryParams['type'];
}
```

and rather than checking for the `null` value in `$type` set the default type when you declare the class attribute change it to

```
public $type='column';
```

Your full code for the class will look like below

```
namespace app\componets\charts;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Widget;
class ChartsWidget extends Widget {

    public $limit;
    public $topten;
    public $type = 'column';

    public function init() {
        parent::init ();
        if ( $this->limit === null ) {
            $this->limit = 10;
        }
        
        $this->topten = $this->GetTopTen ();
        
        if ( isset ( Yii::$app->request->queryParams['type'] ) ) {
            $this->type = Yii::$app->request->queryParams['type'];
        }
    }

    private function GetTopTen() {
        $connection = Yii::$app->getDb ();

        $command = $connection->createCommand ( "SELECT colonias.nomasen AS name, count(rv.geom) AS conteo FROM colonias LEFT JOIN rv ON ST_Contains(colonias.geom, rv.geom) WHERE colonias.nomasen!='NINGUNO'  GROUP BY  colonias.nomasen ORDER BY conteo DESC LIMIT :limit" )->bindValue ( ':limit' , $this->limit );

        $tops = $command->queryAll ();
        
        foreach ( $tops as $top ) {
            $topten['names'][] = $top['name'];
            $topten['conteos'][] = $this->ToInt ( $top['conteo'] );
        }

        return $topten;
    }

    private function ToInt( $valor ) {
        return ( int ) $valor;
    }

    public function run() {
        return $this->render ( 'charts' , [ 'topten' => $this->topten , 'limit' => $this->limit , 'type' => $this->type ] );
    }

}
```

---

### EDIT 2

As the currently assigned data is the array

```
$data = ["column", "bar", "pie"];
```

and the above-given code where we are binding the `select2-select` event we are using `$(this).val()` which will pass integer value rather than the actual string you can either change the array to hold name value pair like

```
$data = ["column"=>"column", "bar"=>"bar", "pie"=>"pie"];
```

or change the javascript code to detect the selected text rather than the value

```
$(this).select2(\"data\")[0].text;
```

Comment: @Maurocrispin the 2 was because i was testing it locally with a dropdown missed to change back , you should not get 404 i tested it with a basic widget code , i am out at the moment from mobile can you exactly add the code that you changed with the view names or if you could share the directory structure it would be easier for me to replicate the same scenario, will update answer once i get back

Comment: I am almost done. Using location='$baseUrl&type='+$(this).val() I get the key (0, 1 or 2) but not the string (column, bar, pie). My reloaded link looks like /index.php?r=maps%2Fmaps&type=1 and it should look like /index.php?r=maps%2Fmaps&type=bar.  How do I get string instead of array key.

Comment: I solved 404 error with "function(e) { location='$baseUrl&type='+$(this).val()}"

Comment: @Maurocrispin the val depends on the data you are providing to the select2 the array with name=>value pair, good to hear you solved it

Comment: @Maurocrispin change your $data array to `$data = ["column",=>"column", "bar"=>"bar", "pie"=>"pie"];`

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing that but I'll take your  advice. Thank you so much you were so helpful.